# Video playback problems

Tags: upgrade, video

I use Ubuntu Studio 19.10 in a HP 250 G5 Laptop Computer, with this specs:

· Intel Pentium N3710 @ 1,6 GHZ;

· 8GB RAM;

· 81F1 Motherboard;

· Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 405 (Braswell);

· ATA Toshiba MQ01ABD1 1 TB Internal HDD.

I had left to use it since last November (2019), because I've been using another device.

Now, I powered-in the laptop and I performed an upgrading to get all the last available upgraded apps, libraries, etc.

When the upgrading process ended, I played a full HD video (1920x1080 px, with Parole), because I need to see some tips (about music notation).

BUT... The audio is almost fine (there is some kind of old vinyl crackle noise). The video... Is not good at all!!! I can see some frames, then others, as a typical still images slide presentation. I cannot to see a normal video playback!!!

What's wrong, here?

It is something related with the upgraded materials itself? ???

Last time I used this laptop, there was not any of this today issues. So...

How can I fix this?

If it is something related with the upgraded materials... How can I come back to the old lib and app versions? ???

Answer (score 0):

I think I found some "solution".

I often use JACK AUDIO CONNECTING SERVER to my audio apps.

If I shutdown all the JACK AUDIO SERVER, I can see the videos, without problems!!!

Well, it is not included an issue I still have with MKV video format (This format cannot to be seen in a right way in this HP Laptop).

In other words... It seem the HP 250 G5 Laptop is not enough capable to use Jack Audio Connecting Server at the same time with the video apps.

If someone knows any way to fix this... I'll appreciate the helping hand!!!